# AV Pipeline Kit Demo not working, what's the problem?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I downloaded the AV Pipeline Kit from [here](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-av-pipeline-demo), but it is not working. And don't give any error but the toast message say that need external storage document for working is it require for working with that kit. When I close the control code block this kit not working again please help me.

I added the screen about my problem, any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In demo there is condition for file that file should be externally add to application from internal storage.

Like following:

[image]

[image]